# NON orthogonal projection : projecting a point onto a line at given direction (2d)

Tags: geometry, 2d, projection

I need a solution to project a 2d point onto a 2d line at certain Direction .Here's what i've got so far : This is how i do orthogonal projection :

```
CVector2d project(Line line , CVector2d point)
{
    CVector2d A = line.end - line.start;
    CVector2d B = point - line start;

    float dot = A.dotProduct(B);
    float mag = A.getMagnitude();

    float md = dot/mag;

    return CVector2d (line.start + A * md);
}
```

Result :

(Projecting P onto line and the result is Pr):

[image]

but i need to project the point onto the line at given DIRECTION which should return a result like this (project point P1 onto line at specific Direction calculate Pr) :

[image]

How should I take Direction vector into account to calculate Pr ?

Answer (score 0):

I can come up with 2 methods out of my head.

Personally I would do this using affine transformations (but seems you don not have this concept as you are using vectors not points). The procedure with affine transformations is easy. Rotate the points to one of the cardinal axes read the coordinate of your point zero the other value and inverse transform back. The reason for this strategy is that nearly all transformation procedures reduce to very simple human understandable operations with the affine transformation scheme. So no real work to do once you have the tools and data structures at hand.

However since you didn't see this coming I assume you want to hear a vector operation instead (because you either prefer the matrix operation or run away when its suggested, tough its the same thing). So you have the following situation:

[image: A example of how the vectors result in your solution]

This expressed as a equation system looks like (its intentionally this way to show you that it is NOT code but math at this point):

```
line.start.x + x*(line.end.x - line.start.x)+ y*direction.x = point.x
line.start.y + x*(line.end.y - line.start.y)+ y*direction.y = point.y
```

now this can be solved for x (and y)

```
x = (direction.y * line.start.x - direction.x * line.start.y -
    direction.y * point.x + direction.x * point.y) /
    (direction.y * line.end.x - direction.x * line.end.y - 
     direction.y * line.start.x + direction.x * line.start.y);

// the solution for y can be omitted you dont need it

y = -(line.end.y * line.start.x - line.end.x * line.start.y - 
      line.end.y * point.x + line.start.y * point.x + line.end.x * point.y - 
      line.start.x point.y)/
     (-direction.y * line.end.x + direction.x * line.end.y + 
      direction.y *  line.start.x - direction.x * line.start.y)
```

Calculation done with mathematica if I didn't copy anything wrong it should work. But I would never use this solution because its not understandable (although it is high school grade math, or at least it is where I am). But use space transformation as described above.

Comment: Hi ! First of all , sorry for the late post , i was busy these days.I finally managed to solve it in a special way(similar to your 2nd suggestion) , however you were right : Affine transformations is the proper (or at least standard way) to solve this , i just need to dig in into more deeply into it... Anyway the solution was very easy : Project the point (P1) onto a vector that's orthogonal to direction. Now we got a new point (lets call it P2) so we just need to find the intersection point between the two lines (line1 and a line between P1,P2)  the result is the projection (Pr on Pic2)